# collision detection in didbegincontact does not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I want every `spritenode` the user creates come with a left and right edge bitmask. Other bitmasks work, but this one don't.

Below the method for creating a new `spritenode`, which is called in `TouchesBegin`

```
-(void)spawnBrick
{
    brick = [[BrickNodeOne alloc] init];
    brick.name = @"Brick";

    NSArray *array = [self objectForKeyedSubscript:@"Brick"];
    BrickNodeOne *oldBrick;
    if ([array count] > 0) {
        oldBrick = [array objectAtIndex:([array count]-1)];
    }
    brick.position = CGPointMake(brick.size.width / 2, (brick.size.height + oldBrick.position.y)-15);
    brick.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(brick.size.width, brick.size.height)];
    brick.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = kBrickCategory;
    brick.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = kCarCategory;
    brick.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
    [self addChild:brick];

    SKAction *moveTo = [SKAction moveByX:0.0 y:-125.0 duration:1.0];
    [brick runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:moveTo]withKey:@"moveDown"];

    _brickRightEdge = [[SKNode alloc] init];
    _brickRightEdge.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeFromPoint:CGPointMake(brick.size.width, 0.0) toPoint:CGPointMake(brick.size.width, brick.size.height)];
    _brickRightEdge.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
    _brickRightEdge.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = brickRightEdgeCategory;
    _brickRightEdge.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = kCarCategory;
    _brickRightEdge.position = brick.position;
    [brick addChild:_brickRightEdge];

    _brickLeftEdge = [[SKNode alloc] init];
    _brickLeftEdge.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeFromPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0) toPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, brick.size.height)];
    _brickLeftEdge.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
    _brickLeftEdge.position = brick.position;
    _brickLeftEdge.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = brickLeftEdgeCategory;
    _brickLeftEdge.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = kCarCategory;
    [brick addChild:_brickLeftEdge];

}
```

The car `spritenode` which I want collision detection with the brick right and left edge is declared in `didMoveToView`

```
  SKSpriteNode *car = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"HighWayCar_Red"];
car.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2, 120);
car.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:car.size];
car.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = kCarCategory;
car.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = kWaterCategory | brickLeftEdgeCategory | brickRightEdgeCategory;
car.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
car.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
car.zPosition = 2;
[self addChild:car];
```

Code `DidBeginContact`

```
  if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == kCarCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == brickLeftEdgeCategory) {
    NSLog(@"HIT");
}
if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == kCarCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == brickRightEdgeCategory) {
    NSLog(@"HIT");
}
```

**Update for comment**

```
I declared `SKPhysicsContactDelegate` in the header file. Set the delegate in `didMoveToView`
```

Bitmasks:

```
static const uint32_t kBrickCategory            = 0x1 << 0;
static const uint32_t leftEdgeCategory          = 0x1 << 1;
static const uint32_t rightEdgeCategory         = 0x1 << 2;
static const uint32_t brickLeftEdgeCategory     = 0x1 << 3;
static const uint32_t brickRightEdgeCategory    = 0x1 << 4;
static const uint32_t kCarCategory              = 0x1 << 5;
static const uint32_t kWaterCategory            = 0x1 << 6;
```

Comment: can you show the way youre creating your bitmasks too

Comment: I updated the question. In between time I thought about deleting the brickCategory and instead using bodyWithBodies method for both left and right edge of the brick.